# writing app specific jquery ajax functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could somebody recommend to me the "proper" way of writing "filter" functions for ajax requests? Maybe by explaining my scenario I can better explain my question:

For all my ajax applications I use a specific JSON response system. Each request response from the server is formatted like so:

```
{"type": "data", "code": "200", "data" : [/* some data here */]}
```

I want to write a function that parses this response, does some logic based on type and code, then passes an object to the callback. However, I want the ability to apply this to MOST requests, but not ALL. Hence I need something more than just the ajax event globals. (Unless you can think of a way to use those and still get control).

Also, I want the ability to write an ajax function that automatically builds the url and data parameter. So all in all, I'm wanting to know what the proper route to writing a function that preps the request, sends the request, returns a deferred, parses the response, and executes the call back. Similar to a before and after filter to the $.ajax function.

That being said, I can imagine that the "before filter" part would be as simple as writing a function that builds the request and sends it. The trouble I'm having is figuring out how I would "catch" the response and parse it before the supplied callback is executed. Especially since I'm wanting to base any action on the status code. Does anyone have any ideas or articles they could share to help?

Comment: If `code` is an [HTTP status code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html), send it as an HTTP status code.

Comment: although the 200 code is a HTTP status code also, the code above is used in the application itself to represent internal application errors and messages.

Comment: That's why I posted as a comment; I figured it was worth checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In In case this helps anyone else, I finally found the answer. In the documentation for the ajax function, there is a VERY small piece of text that says it's possible to extend the function. The link for those of you who were like me and never noticed it is this: http://api.jquery.com/extending-ajax

Hope that helps someone like it helped me!

** **EDIT** **

I actually found a better way than that. I ended up using jQuery's pipe method as explained here: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2255-Using-jQuery-s-Pipe-Method-To-Change-Deferred-Resolution.htm

And that worked perfectly! it allowed be to catch the response before the callback, then filter the result and even keep the callback from calling if I so wished. Hope this will be helpful to somebody else too.